# What does the mb prefix signify when attached to some jquery plugins?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am looking at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/51

and seeing (mb)Tooltip, (mb)Containers, etc.

**what is mb?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's just the author: Matteo Bicocchi.